# How do I retrieve a field value from Firebase using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to learn Firebase. I made a very simple ReactApp along with a very simple database in Firebase. I am so beyond confused as to how to access a field's value. I'm sure this is an extremely simple question, but somehow, I am missing how to find the solution.

My database looks as such:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgg71.jpg

I really would like to know how to access the "Speed" field value.

I have tried

```
const db = firebase.database.ref();
const speedRef = 
db.child('react').child('mySpeed').once('value').then(snap =>{
  if (snap.val()){
    this.setState({ speed: snap.val().speed });
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
})
```

Along with

```
const speedRef = firebase.database().ref().child('mySpeed').child('speed');
speedRef.on('value', snap => {
  this.setState({ speed: snap.val() });
})
```

To no avail. I really hope someone can help me understand this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like you might be using the Firebase Cloud Firestore, not Firebase Realtime Database. Are you intending to use Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore? If you are using Firestore, the realtime database code you have in your question will simply not work.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that is most likely my issue, as I was not aware that it was set to Firestore by default when you click on the 'Database' from the console. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***try to use this: ***

```js
const react = firebase.database().ref("react");
react.child("mySpeed").child("speed").once("value").then(data => {
  if(data.val() !== null){
     console.log(data.val());
  }
});
```

Comment: @Alex Good :) Do not forget to check the useful answer.

Comment: So the actual reason was because I was not using the Realtime Database, I was using the Firestore. I'm sure your code may have worked, but I followed a tutorial straight from the Firebase people, and was able to get my code up and running. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Alex You Welcome Bro ^_^